# use page transitions with react router dom

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

I am trying to use an animation i.e. page transition with react-router-dom using the object version for the declaration. I don't seem to find how to specify what animation to use.

So I have:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <CustomLayout />,
        loader: _ => {
            resetParameters()
            return null
        },
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <HomePage />,
                loader: _ => {
                    resetParameters()
                    return null
                }]
}
```

Where do I specify the animation transition. I am looking for something like this sample from https://github.com/Steveeeie/react-page-transition but adapted to RRDv6 :

```
<PageTransition
              preset="moveToLeftFromRight"
              transitionKey={location.pathname}
            >
              <Switch location={location}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
              </Switch>
            </PageTransition>
```

which is fine if I were to use the tags, but I am using the object definition.

This sample is using https://github.com/Steveeeie/react-page-transition but it could be any other transition library.

An alternative would be to use the RRDv5 tags which are still supported in RRDv6 i.e. ... but this prevents the usage of the APIs in RRDv6 (all of the useXXX methods) which I need.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` (RRD) are you actually trying to use here? The first code snippet is using RRDv6 components and APIs, the second is using RRDv5 components and APIs.

Comment: I am using the latest version of RRD, I was just trying to find out how to integrate with the latest version, knowing that the sample from Steveeie is indeed using RRDv5. I have updated the question to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: From what I understand of using route transitions in RRDv6, they all involve passing a current location to the `Routes` component, which isn't used in the Data Router APIs. If you don't need the Data APIs then try a regular `BrowserRouter` and `Routes` (*replaced `Switch`, BTW*) to get transitions working.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, unfortunately I need to use the api's but I still believe there should be a way to have transitions in RRDv6 even if not with the  https://github.com/Steveeeie/react-page-transition  package. Not being able to use any transition for a router package seems a bit odd.

Comment: Nope, never worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a beginner so my code might be horrible but I managed to make a working version of the page transition using framer-motion, RouterProvider, and createBrowserRouter.

App.jsx

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage/HomePage'
import DummyPage from './pages/DummyPage/DummyPage'
import React from 'react'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: '/', element: <HomePage /> },
  { path: '/dummy', element: <DummyPage /> },
])

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}

export default App
```

Instead of using Link from react-router-dom I made a custom component for that.

CustomLink.jsx

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import './CustomLink.css'
function CustomLink({ dest, content, setExit }) {
  console.log(dest)
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleDelayedLinkClick = (to, delay) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setExit(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate(to)
    }, delay)
  }

  return (
    <div className='link' onClick={handleDelayedLinkClick(dest, 1000)}>
      {content}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomLink
```

Now I used this custom link in my page components.

HomePage.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './HomePage.css'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'
import CustomLink from '../../components/CustomLink'
const HomePage = () => {
  const [exit, setExit] = useState(false)
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {!exit && (
        <motion.div
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          className='container'
        >
          <div>This is HomePage</div>
          <div>
            Click to navigate to{' '}
            <CustomLink dest={'/dummy'} content={'Dummy'} setExit={setExit} />
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

DummyPage.jsx

```
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './DummyPage.css'
import CustomLink from '../../components/CustomLink'
import { useState } from 'react'
const DummyPage = () => {
  const [exit, setExit] = useState(false)
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {!exit && (
        <motion.div
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          className='dummy-container'
        >
          <div>This is DummyPage</div>
          <div>
            Click to navigate to{' '}
            <CustomLink dest={'/'} content={'Home'} setExit={setExit} />
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}

export default DummyPage
```

With this, I was able to do a fade-in and fade-out transition on-page navigation. If you don't have links and want to conditionally navigate to another page you can use a state to conditionally render the component, wrap it in animate presence. You can make a custom hook to handle this logic. Hope this helps.

Code sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/page-transition-trial-npq3md?file=/src/App.jsx)